# Enable zooming in WKWebView in Swift 4, Xcode 10, for iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to enable zooming/magnification (by pinching) in a very simple WebView in a simple app. (I am pretty new to this).

The Swift code that loads the web page is this and it works fine, I got from here, I think.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {    

@IBOutlet weak var WebViewSchedule: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 // load the page
    let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    WebViewSchedule.load(request)
//how do i make it zoomable ????
 }
}
```

I've looked at a number of answers about this, and they all refer to a property "allowsMagnification".  I have tried various ways of using this and got nowhere.

So could some  kind person give me a beginners' guide to how to make my iOS Web page zoomable?

Comment: I found in the docs, allowsMagnification is macOS 10.10+ only, not on iOS

Comment: I think you need to implement viewForZoomingInScrollView

Comment: Aha. Thanks. That sounds like a start .  Thanks .....

Comment: I would like to share a really helpful tutorial on a related matter that may help others googling this question.  I have found several Youtube videos with rather long-winded ways of scaling images, but this is a very simple one. https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/scale-images-with-pinch-gesture-ios-tutorial-ios10